# How to estimate how heavy a tail is?

Tags: estimation, nonparametric, estimators, heavy-tailed

Suppose I have data coming from a single variate distribution. I want to estimate how heavy the tail of the distribution is. For example, if the data comes from the Zipf distribution, I would want the estimator to estimate the $\alpha$ parameter. However, I would like a non-parametric estimator.

What are some commonly used estimators? I have found a [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1010012224103), but the paper has surprisingly few citations, so I'm curious if there is anything else that people use?

Comment: 192 citations for such a specialised publication is pretty decent. Not all papers have VGG16 citation levels.

Comment: I would expect a foundational stats paper with very important results to have multiple hundreds of citations. Many such papers have thousands.

Comment: Googling "estimating tail index" brings up many things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at ["So You Think You Have a Power Law — Well Isn't That Special?"](http://bactra.org/weblog/491.html)

And the paper underlying the post with 10,000+ citations:
https://www.jstor.org/stable/25662336

Also comes with Matlab and R code.